# Haskell, syntax error

Tags: parsing, haskell, syntax

```
temperatura :: Float->Float
temperatura qCalor
    | qCalor == 0 = 10
    | 0 < qCalor < 3 = 30--fTem1
    | 3 <= qCalor <= 9 = 50
    | qCalor > 9 = 60--fTemp2
    | 15 <= qCalor <= 24 = 150
    | 24 < qCalor <= 27 = 170--fTemp3
    | otherwise = "Nao existe temperatura correspondente a esse calor no grafico!"
```

Precedence parse error
why is that?

Answer (score 8):

First, when asking a question it's helpful to post the actual error. Here is what I got:

```
test.hs:3:7:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `<' [infix 4] and `<' [infix 4] in the same infix expression

test.hs:4:7:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `<=' [infix 4] and `<=' [infix 4] in the same infix expression

test.hs:6:7:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `<=' [infix 4] and `<=' [infix 4] in the same infix expression


test.hs:7:7:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `<' [infix 4] and `<=' [infix 4] in the same infix expression
```

---

Now, the problem is basically that `<` (and the other comparison operators) are really just binary functions - functions that take two arguments. The compiler is telling you that it has no way to know how to place parenthesis in the expressions, because those functions have the same precedence level. Take, for example, this one:

```
| 0 < qCalor < 3 = 30
```

The compiler doesn't know whether it means `(0 < qCalor) < 3` or `0 < (qCalor < 3)`. In any case there is no reasonable typing for that line.

I suggest something like `(0 < qCalor) && (qCalor < 3)`, or better yet, use a function such as (there's probably a builtin one for this):

```
betweenNums a b c = (a < b) && (b < c)
```

Comment: The parens for the last example aren't needed, `&&` has a lower precedence

Comment: @jozefg, in my opinion the parens are needed for readability

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_guidelines#Application_notation Haskell generally embraces infix's

Comment: @jozefg, it's really a matter of taste, there's nothing wrong in adding a few parens to make things clearer.

Comment: No no your right, it is. I just thought that it was worth pointing out just to make it clear that it's possible, especially since the OP was originally trying to avoid verbose syntax. But your right it's a matter of taste.

Comment: By the way, *if* you're the one who downvoted this answer, it's worth at least explaining why the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Note that python-style expressions like:

```
x < y < z
```

are not legal Haskell.
Even this wouldn't be right:

```
(x < y) < z
```

Because:

```
Prelude> :t (<)
(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

The things you compare with <, >, <=, and >= have to be the same type. `(x < y)` would yield a Bool. The next step (in your case) would thus be `Bool < Float` which isn't possible.